# Bad idea to define window and widget size in pixels?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it a bad idea to define window and widget sizes in pixels, if I want to keep a GUI in a good shape on any screen? Is text always displayed with the same pixel size, and does the text in the following example fit the white box on any screen? Is there an option in tkinter to use points instead of pixels?

[image: Screenshot]

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100+400+200")
root.configure(background='black')
lbl = tk.Label(text="This is a test.", bg='white')
lbl.place(x=20, y=20, width=68, height=11)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a bad idea, yes. Define the relationships you want and tkinter figure out the pixel locations.

If I run your code on my computer I get this:

[image]

(probably because I have a different default font then you do)

Comment: Good to know! How would you solve this using tkinter? The text height should probably define the size of everything else. Starting with the window size, how to set the window size in units of text height?

Comment: @NablaDelta Ideally, you don't set the window size at all. Let tkinter figure out how large the window needs to be. Set the ideal font size knowing the user's preferences may override that, and forget about anything else.